# store.dispatch is not function in vuex state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

Hi i am trying to validate the token when page loads with vue js , after verification i want to store the user in state with the help of vuex store . But i am having this error store.dispatch is not function.

My service file looks like this.

```
const store = require('../store/index.js');

const api_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'

exports.checkValidation = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            let token = localStorage.getItem('t');
            console.log('found token', token);
            const headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
            const body = {
                token: token
            }
            const url = api_url + 'checkvalidation'

            axios.post(url, body, headers)
                .then((result) => {
                    console.log(result.data)
                    store.dispatch('setLoggedInUserData', result.data.user)
                    resolve(result.data)
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err)
                    reject('Error')
                })
        } catch (e) {
            reject(e)
        }
    })
}
```

and store/index.js looks like this

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
import states from './states';
import mutations from './mutations';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';

export default createStore({
    state: states,
    mutations: mutations,
    actions: actions,
    modules: {},
    getters: getters
})
```

any help is appreciated .

Comment: try `import store from '../store'`

Comment: the `export` doesn't seem right in your service file - it's not serving the `ESM` format that you use for `import`ing. So, you either use `exports -> require` (CommonJS) or the `export -> import` (ESM) - you cannot mix those.

Comment: Yes i ahve fixed that  by converting to ES6 . Happy Coding